# Swipe up or pull up to refresh in React-Native

Tags: react-native, refresh, swipe, gesture, flatlist

I am trying to implement a feature in which whenever I went to end the end of the FlatList and then when I swipe up or pull up for some small time, then this acts as a refresh and required data get loaded. Also the flatlist is long so we reach the end of the list in some time. Please help in this as I can't get any resources available for the same.

I tried using various packages like react-native-gesture-handler etc. but couldn't get the solution which I am hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

> you can use onMomentumScrollEnd which is provided by FlatList

```
const handleMomentumScrollEnd = () => {
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout.current);

    if (prevY.current > 50) {
      setRefreshing(true);

      setTimeout(() => {
        setRefreshing(false);
      }, 2000);
    }
  };
```

you can check this expo snack link to view the full code.
[Expo](https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/onmomentscroll)

Answer (score 0):

Reaching the end of FlatlList amd pulling up are two different thing

For Reaching end of the list You can detect by `onEndReached` callback.
For Refreshing (Pull to refresh) You can use `[RefreshControl][1]`

Please see the below Example

```
// Logic for onEndReached

const onEndReached= ()=>{
do Your styff
}
<FlatList
   refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }>
  data={yourArray}
  renderItem={yourRenderItem}
onEndReached= {onEndReached}

/>
```

Comment: this refresh is for pull down one, but I need to get refresh after reaching the end of list and then pulling up